# 0 displayed after saving entry on View Entry Page

Tags: custom-fields

I have a channel with about 12 custom fields. Nothing complicated, mostly text input, a few text areas, two files and one relationship field.

I noticed after I create an entry and click save, the next screen which is called 'View Entry' displays all the data I entered BUT also shows a zero.

I thought it odd, so re-installed EE Core. Remade my channel and its custom fields but once again, I keep getting shown a 0. It seems that one of the fields is defaulting to the 0. I recheck all of them 100s of time, they all look fine.

I seem to recall that back in the 1.4 EE days, I encountered this problem as well.

Anyone have a reason as to why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One thing that would do that is if you have one of your text fields with the "Field Content" option set to something other than "all" - number, integer or decimal - I can't remember which it is - it may be more than one of them - that defaults to zero when the field is left blank.

Comment: I also thought I might have a field not set to ALL! I checked and the text input fields are indeed set to ALL.